# Custom TableController<> offline sync backend for use with Azure Client SDK IMobileServiceSyncTable app

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

We are developing an Android app with Xamarin and want to use offline sync but we cannot connect our DTOs directly to the database, as is done in almost all examples and the Quickstart solution one can download from the Azure portal.

For now I'm using the ToDo sample app downloaded from the Azure portal, which by default is mapped to the address https://myappname.azurewebsites.net.

I have a WebApi application, whose address I put in the ToDo app's settings and with a catch-all route saw that the app calls the address http://mywebapidev/tables/todoitem. In the WebApi application I added the route /tables/{controller} route and a controller called ToDoItemController, which inherits from TableController.

I also implemented my own DomainManager, which I'm setting in Initialize

```
public class ToDoItemController : TableController<ToDoItem>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        this.DomainManager = new MyDomainManager();
    }
}
```

My question is, what do I need to implement (in the controller and elsewhere) for it to be able to work as the backend for Azure Client SDK offline sync?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read http://aka.ms/zumobook - especially chapter 3.  It goes through the process of offline sync rather thoroughly.

Short version though:

1. You need a DateTimeOffset type in your model so the service can do incremental sync
2. You need a Version column (opaque) so the service can do conflict resolution.
3. You need to convert the OData query into LINQ and then LINQ into your specific requirements.  This is the hard part.

Comment: Are the actions and their names in the controller convention based, like GetAllExample?

Comment: You can use decorators as well.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit, or a lot? I'm stuck and there seems to be no information anywhere. E.g. in the examples in the Zumo book in the controller is a method public async Task<IEnumerable<TodoItem>> GetAllTodoItemsAsync(ODataQueryOptions query). How does this ever get called? There are no attributes on any methods.

Comment: All of the examples use convention over decorators.  However, at the end of the day, a controller is just an ApiController (eventually), so it has all the normal routing / etc.  I'd stay with convention, personally, as that is what we test extensively.